# How to transpose and "pile" the columns on a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to do "a pile" of different indicator I have on a dataframe on just one column
So I have something like this:

> 

```
import pandas as pd
f={ 'Country': ['UK', 'Germany', 'France'],
    'Class': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'Price': ['50', '30', '50']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
```

so:

```
    Country Class   Price
0   UK      1       50
1   Germany 2       30
2   France  3       50
```

and I would like something like this:

```
    Country Indicators  Value
0   UK      Class       1
1   UK      Price       50
2   Germany Class       2
3   Germany Price       30
4   France  Class       3
5   France  Price       50
```

Tried Transpose but it is not that..
I do not have a clue

Comment: kindly explain your logic

Comment: What is `Class`? what is `Price`? Where did those numbers come from in your desired output?

Comment: I missed the concept of "stack". My goal was to get just one column of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your sample data could be missing some values. It could be:

```
f={    'Country': ['UK', 'Germany', 'France'],
    'Class': ['50', '10', '50'],
    'Price': ['30', '35', '20']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f)


   Country Class Price
0       UK    50    30
1  Germany    10    35
2   France    50    20
```

Then to get the output you want, you can use [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) as follows:

```
df1.melt(id_vars='Country', value_vars=['Class', 'Price'], var_name='Indicators', value_name='Value').sort_values('Country', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
   Country Indicators Value
0       UK      Class    50
3       UK      Price    30
1  Germany      Class    10
4  Germany      Price    35
2   France      Class    50
5   France      Price    20
```

Another solution is to use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), as follows:

```
df1.set_index('Country').stack().rename_axis(index=['Country','Indicators']).to_frame(name='Value').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Country Indicators Value
0       UK      Class    50
3       UK      Price    30
1  Germany      Class    10
4  Germany      Price    35
2   France      Class    50
5   France      Price    20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack()` to meet your goal.

But before that, you should set the row index using column `Country`, then perform `stack()`. Finally reset the row index using `reset_index()`.

```
df1.set_index('Country').stack().reset_index()
```

Output

[image]